# Arduino LED Controller hanging at startup

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to code an LED controller that controls the intensity via PWM. However, my issue is that I can't even get to the loop portion, it seems to hang at when I declare my class. I've tried checking to see if any of my functions in my class are causing the issues, but since I can't even get to loop, there must be something wrong within the class. I've written the class and placed it into a library called LED.

The code is somewhat long, but here it is:

```cpp
#ifndef LED_H
#define LED_H

#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <Button.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <TimeLib.h>
#include <PWM.h>

class LED
{
public:

    LED();
    int read_encoder(); //Reads rotary encoder
    void clearLCD();
    void setAllLed();
    void printLCD();
    void setOneLed(int);
    int   setLed(int,         // current time in minutes
                 int,        // pin for this channel of LEDs
                 int,         // start time for this channel of LEDs
                 int,        // photoperiod for this channel of LEDs
                 int,          // fade duration for this channel of LEDs
                 int,        // max value for this channel
                 bool   // true if the channel is inverted
                );
    void menuWizard();
    int subMenuWizard(int, int, bool, bool);
    void displayMainMenu();
    void printMins(int, bool);
    void printHMS(byte,byte,byte);
    long EEPROMReadlong(long);
    void EEPROMWritelong(int, long);
    bool pressSelect();
    bool pressBack();
    void rotateCheck(int&, int, int);

    //variables for the LED channels
    int minCounter = 0;         // counter that resets at midnight.
    int oldMinCounter = 0;      // counter that resets at midnight.

    int ledPins[5]={2,3,5,6,7};

    int ledVal[5]={0,0,0,0,0};

    // Variables making use of EEPROM memory:
    int variablesList[20];

    bool invertedLEDs[5]={false,false,false,false,false};

    //Backlight Variables
    unsigned long backlightIdleMs = 0;




private:
};

#endif // LED_H
```

And here is the .cpp file:

```cpp
            #define LCD_RS 35        // RS pin
            #define LCD_ENABLE 34    // enable pin
            #define LCD_DATA4 33     // d4 pin
            #define LCD_DATA5 32     // d5 pin
            #define LCD_DATA6 31    // d6 pin
            #define LCD_DATA7 30     // d7 pin
            #define LCD_BACKLIGHT 9 // backlight pin

            // Backlight config
            #define BACKLIGHT_DIM 10              // PWM value for backlight at idle
            #define BACKLIGHT_ON 70               // PWM value for backlight when on
            #define BACKLIGHT_IDLE_MS 10000 // Backlight idle delay

            #define ENC_A 14
            #define ENC_B 15
            #define ENC_PORT PINC

            #include <LiquidCrystal.h>
            #include <Button.h>
            #include <EEPROM.h>
            #include <TimeLib.h>
            #include <PWM.h>
            #include "LED.h"


            LiquidCrystal lcd(LCD_RS, LCD_ENABLE, LCD_DATA4, LCD_DATA5, LCD_DATA6, LCD_DATA7);
            Button goBack=Button(12, PULLDOWN);
            Button select=Button(13, PULLDOWN);


            LED::LED()
            {
            InitTimersSafe();

            pinMode(LCD_BACKLIGHT, OUTPUT);
              lcd.begin(16, 2);
              digitalWrite(LCD_BACKLIGHT, HIGH);
              lcd.print("sEx LED, V1");
              clearLCD();
              delay(5000);
              analogWrite(LCD_BACKLIGHT, BACKLIGHT_DIM);

             if (variablesList[0] > 1440 || variablesList[0] < 0) {
                        variablesList[0] = 720;      // minute to start this channel.
                        variablesList[1] = 400;    // photoperiod in minutes for this channel.
                        variablesList[2] = 100;                       // max intensity for this channel, as a percentage
                        variablesList[3] = 100;  // duration of the fade on and off for sunrise and sunset for
                        //    this channel.
                        variablesList[4] = 720;
                        variablesList[5] = 400;
                        variablesList[6] = 100;
                        variablesList[7] = 100;

                        variablesList[8] = 720;
                        variablesList[9] = 400;
                        variablesList[10] = 100;
                        variablesList[11] = 100;

                        variablesList[12] = 720;
                        variablesList[13] = 400;
                        variablesList[14] = 100;
                        variablesList[15] = 100;

                        variablesList[16] = 720;
                        variablesList[17] = 400;
                        variablesList[18] = 100;
                        variablesList[19] = 100;

                }

                else {

                     variablesList[0] = EEPROMReadlong(0);      // minute to start this channel.
                     variablesList[1] = EEPROMReadlong(4);    // photoperiod in minutes for this channel.
                     variablesList[2] = EEPROMReadlong(8);                      // max intensity for this channel, as a percentage
                     variablesList[3] = EEPROMReadlong(12);  // duration of the fade on and off for sunrise and sunset for
                                                                //    this channel.
                     variablesList[4] = EEPROMReadlong(16);
                     variablesList[5] = EEPROMReadlong(20);
                     variablesList[6] = EEPROMReadlong(24);
                     variablesList[7] = EEPROMReadlong(28);

                     variablesList[8] = EEPROMReadlong(32);
                     variablesList[9] = EEPROMReadlong(36);
                     variablesList[10] = EEPROMReadlong(40);
                     variablesList[11] = EEPROMReadlong(44);

                     variablesList[12] = EEPROMReadlong(48);
                     variablesList[13] = EEPROMReadlong(52);
                     variablesList[14] = EEPROMReadlong(56);
                     variablesList[15] = EEPROMReadlong(60);

                     variablesList[16] = EEPROMReadlong(64);
                     variablesList[17] = EEPROMReadlong(68);
                     variablesList[18] = EEPROMReadlong(72);
                     variablesList[19] = EEPROMReadlong(76);

                }

            }


            void LED::printLCD(){lcd.print("test");clearLCD();delay(2000);lcd.print("testing");clearLCD();}

            bool LED::pressSelect(){

                if (select.uniquePress()){return 1;}

                else {return 0;}


            }
            bool LED::pressBack(){

                if (goBack.uniquePress()){return 1;}

                else {return 0;}


            }

            void LED::clearLCD(){

            lcd.clear();

            }

            void LED::displayMainMenu(){

                oldMinCounter = minCounter;
                minCounter = hour() * 60 + minute();

                for (int i=0;i<17;i=i+4){

                     if (variablesList[i+3] > variablesList[i+1] / 2 && variablesList[i+1] > 0) {
                        variablesList[i+3] = variablesList[i+1] / 2;
                     }
                    if (variablesList[i+3] < 1) {
                        variablesList[i+3] = 1;
                    }

                }




              //check & set any time functions

               if (minCounter > oldMinCounter) {
                  lcd.clear();
                }
                lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
                printHMS(hour(), minute(), second());
                lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
                lcd.print(ledVal[0]);
                lcd.setCursor(4, 1);
                lcd.print(ledVal[1]);
                lcd.setCursor(8, 1);
                lcd.print(ledVal[2]);


            }

            int LED::read_encoder()
            {
              static int enc_states[] = {0,-1,1,0,1,0,0,-1,-1,0,0,1,0,1,-1,0};
              static int old_AB = 0;
              /**/
              old_AB <<= 2;                   //remember previous state
              old_AB |= ( ENC_PORT & 0x03 );  //add current state
              return ( enc_states[( old_AB & 0x0f )]);
            }

            int LED::setLed(int mins,         // current time in minutes
                         int ledPin,        // pin for this channel of LEDs
                         int start,         // start time for this channel of LEDs
                         int period,        // photoperiod for this channel of LEDs
                         int fade,          // fade duration for this channel of LEDs
                         int ledMax,        // max value for this channel
                         bool inverted   // true if the channel is inverted
                        )  {
              int val = 0;

              //fade up
              if (mins > start || mins <= start + fade)  {
                val = map(mins - start, 0, fade, 0, ledMax);
              }
              //fade down
              if (mins > start + period - fade && mins <= start + period)  {
                val = map(mins - (start + period - fade), 0, fade, ledMax, 0);
              }
              //off or post-midnight run.
              if (mins <= start || mins > start + period)  {
                if ((start + period) % 1440 < start && (start + period) % 1440 > mins )
                {
                  val = map((start + period - mins) % 1440, 0, fade, 0, ledMax);
                }
                else
                  val = 0;
              }


              if (val > ledMax)  {
                val = ledMax;
              }
              if (val < 0) {
                val = 0;
              }

              if (inverted) {
                pwmWrite(ledPin, map(val, 0, 100, 255, 0));
              }
              else {
                pwmWrite(ledPin, map(val, 0, 100, 0, 255));
              }
              return val;
            }

            void LED::printMins(int mins,       //time in minutes to print
                           bool ampm    //print am/pm?
                          )  {
              int hr = (mins % 1440) / 60;
              int mn = mins % 60;
              if (hr < 10) {
                lcd.print(" ");
              }
              lcd.print(hr);
              lcd.print(":");
              if (mn < 10) {
                lcd.print("0");
              }
              lcd.print(mn);
            }

            void LED::printHMS (byte hr,
                           byte mn,
                           byte sec      //time to print
                          )
            {

              if (hr < 10) {
                lcd.print(" ");
              }
              lcd.print(hr, DEC);
              lcd.print(":");
              if (mn < 10) {
                lcd.print("0");
              }
              lcd.print(mn, DEC);
              lcd.print(":");
              if (sec < 10) {
                lcd.print("0");
              }
              lcd.print(sec, DEC);
            }

            //EEPROM write functions
            long LED::EEPROMReadlong(long address)
            {
              //Read the 4 bytes from the eeprom memory.
              long four = EEPROM.read(address);
              long three = EEPROM.read(address + 1);
              long two = EEPROM.read(address + 2);
              long one = EEPROM.read(address + 3);

              //Return the recomposed long by using bitshift.
              return ((four << 0) & 0xFF) + ((three << 8) & 0xFFFF) + ((two << 16) & 0xFFFFFF) + ((one << 24) & 0xFFFFFFFF);
            }

            void LED::EEPROMWritelong(int address, long value)
            {
              //Decomposition from a long to 4 bytes by using bitshift.
              //One = Most significant -> Four = Least significant byte
              byte four = (value & 0xFF);
              byte three = ((value >> 8) & 0xFF);
              byte two = ((value >> 16) & 0xFF);
              byte one = ((value >> 24) & 0xFF);

              //Write the 4 bytes into the eeprom memory.
              EEPROM.write(address, four);
              EEPROM.write(address + 1, three);
              EEPROM.write(address + 2, two);
              EEPROM.write(address + 3, one);
            }

            void LED::setAllLed(){

                int j=0;

                for (int i=0;i<17;i=i+4){

                    int a=i;int b=i+1;int c=i+2;int d=i+3;

                    ledVal[j] = setLed(minCounter, ledPins[j], variablesList[a], variablesList[b], variablesList[c], variablesList[d], invertedLEDs[j]);
                    j++;

                }

            }

            void LED::setOneLed(int channel){

                int j=channel;
                int i=0;

                if(channel==1){i+=4;}
                if(channel==2){i+=8;}
                if(channel==3){i+=12;}
                if(channel==4){i+=16;}

                int a=i;int b=i+1;int c=i+2;int d=i+3;

                ledVal[j] = setLed(minCounter, ledPins[j], variablesList[a], variablesList[b], variablesList[c], variablesList[d], invertedLEDs[j]);



            }

            void LED::rotateCheck(int& menuCount, int minMenu, int maxMenu){

                while (menuCount!=0){

                    int rotateCount;
                    rotateCount=read_encoder();

                  if (rotateCount) {

                      menuCount+=rotateCount;

                      if (menuCount<minMenu){menuCount==maxMenu;}
                      if (menuCount>maxMenu){menuCount==minMenu;}

                    clearLCD();
                    }
                }

            }

            void LED::menuWizard(){

                int menuCount=1;
                String menuList[6]={"Time","LED Max","LED Start","LED End","Fade Length","Ch Override"};
                String channelList[5]={"1","2","3","4","5"};



                while (menuCount!=0){

                   rotateCheck(menuCount,1,6);

                    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
                    lcd.print(menuList[menuCount-1]);
                    clearLCD();

                    if (goBack.isPressed()){

                        menuCount=0;

                    }

                    if (pressSelect() && menuCount!=0){

                        int timeMode=1;
                        int channelCount=0;
                        bool goBack=0;

                        while (goBack!=1){

                            if (menuCount==1){

                                if (pressSelect()){

                                    timeMode++;

                                    if (timeMode>2){timeMode=1;}

                                }

                                int timeAdjDetect=read_encoder();

                                if (timeMode==1){

                                    if (timeAdjDetect){

                                        if (timeAdjDetect>0){adjustTime(SECS_PER_HOUR);}
                                        if (timeAdjDetect<0) {adjustTime(-SECS_PER_HOUR);}

                                    }

                                    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
                                    lcd.print("Set Time: Hrs");
                                    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
                                    printHMS(hour(), minute(), second());

                                }

                                else{

                                    if (timeAdjDetect){

                                        if (timeAdjDetect>0){adjustTime(SECS_PER_MIN);}
                                        if (timeAdjDetect<0) {adjustTime(-SECS_PER_MIN);}

                                    }

                                    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
                                    lcd.print("Set Time: Mins");
                                    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
                                    printHMS(hour(), minute(), second());

                                }

                                clearLCD();

                            }

                            else{

                                rotateCheck(channelCount,0,4);

                                lcd.setCursor(0,0);
                                lcd.print("Select Channel");
                                lcd.setCursor(0,1);
                                lcd.print(channelList[channelCount]);
                                clearLCD();

                                if (pressSelect()){

                                    if (menuCount==2){

                                        subMenuWizard(2,channelCount,0,0);

                                    }

                                    if (menuCount==3){

                                        subMenuWizard(0,channelCount,1,0);

                                    }

                                    if (menuCount==4){

                                        subMenuWizard(1,channelCount,1,1);

                                    }

                                    if (menuCount==5){

                                        subMenuWizard(3,channelCount,1,0);

                                    }

                                }


                            }

                                if (pressBack()){goBack=1;}

                            }

                    }


                }




                for (int i=0;i<20;i++){

                    int j=0;

                    EEPROMWritelong(j, variablesList[i]);

                    j+=4;

                }

            }

            int LED::subMenuWizard(int i, int channel, bool time, bool truetime){

                if (channel==1){i=i+4;}
                if (channel==2){i=i+8;}
                if (channel==3){i=i+12;}
                if (channel==4){i=i+16;}

                while (!pressBack()){

                    if (time==0){

                        rotateCheck(variablesList[i],0,100);

                        lcd.setCursor(0,0);
                        lcd.print("Set:");
                        lcd.setCursor(0,1);
                        lcd.print(variablesList[i]);

                        setOneLed(channel);
                        clearLCD();

                    }

                    else{

                        if (truetime){

                        rotateCheck(variablesList[i],0,1439);

                        lcd.setCursor(0,0);
                        lcd.print("Set:");
                        lcd.setCursor(0,1);
                        printMins(variablesList[i] + variablesList[i-1], true);
                        clearLCD();

                        }

                        else {

                            rotateCheck(variablesList[i],0,1439);

                            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
                            lcd.print("Set:");
                            lcd.setCursor(0,1);
                            printMins(variablesList[i], true);
                            clearLCD();

                        }

                        setOneLed(channel);

                    }


                }



            }
```

and finally, the .ino file:

```cpp
    #define LCD_BACKLIGHT 9 // backlight pin
    #define BACKLIGHT_DIM 10              // PWM value for backlight at idle
    #define BACKLIGHT_ON 70               // PWM value for backlight when on
    #define BACKLIGHT_IDLE_MS 10000 // Backlight idle delay


    #include <LED.h>


    //Initialize buttons
    int buttonCount = 1;

    LED main;

    void setup() {


    };

    void loop() {
     /* main.setAllLed();

      //turn the backlight off and reset the menu if the idle time has elapsed
      if (main.backlightIdleMs + BACKLIGHT_IDLE_MS < millis() && main.backlightIdleMs > 0 ) {
       analogWrite(LCD_BACKLIGHT, BACKLIGHT_DIM);
      main.clearLCD();
      main.backlightIdleMs = 0;
      }



      if (buttonCount == 1) {

        main.displayMainMenu();

      }

      if (buttonCount == 2) {

        main.menuWizard();
        buttonCount = 1;

      }


    */
    main.printLCD();
    };
```

Also, in the loop portion, I've commented the part of code that is intended to run, and I'm running a function that tests to see if I've successfully entered the loop by printing "test" on screen.

I'm using a Mega for this.

Comment: Is `main` allowed as a variable name?

Comment: I think so, as far as I know. I'm somewhat new to programming in the Arduino IDE. I'll try another name and see what happens.
EDIT: Nothing changed. I think that is not the issue.

Comment: I think you should use the serialPort to debug and check some points to see where the code is hanging up.

Answer (score 1):

```
LED::LED()
            {
            InitTimersSafe();

            pinMode(LCD_BACKLIGHT, OUTPUT);
              lcd.begin(16, 2);
              digitalWrite(LCD_BACKLIGHT, HIGH);
              lcd.print("sEx LED, V1");
              clearLCD();
              delay(5000);
              analogWrite(LCD_BACKLIGHT, BACKLIGHT_DIM);
```

You have to understand that this constructor is running when the object is created and that is probably before init() is run from main.  So the hardware isn't ready at that point and pinMode and digitalWrite and stuff isn't going to work.  The lcd code can't really work there and I bet that is the part that is hanging things.

A constructor should only do things like initialize variables.  Any code that relies on the hardware should go into a begin() or init() or whatever method that you can call from setup once it is safe to do those things.  The Serial object is a great example of another class that has to do this.

Comment: Let me try this. I probably wouldn't have an issue if I just wrote everything out in the .ino file and initialized things in setup, but I was trying to avoid a huge block of code and make things orderly. I will try this and see what happens.

Comment: No need to put all those individual lines in the setup function and have some huge block of code there.  Write a member function of your class and call it void LED::begin() and put it all in there.